# Set type of an array when initializing a class

Tags: arrays, class, swift, initialization

I have a class called Controller that contains one Array property. Right now, my class is declared like that:

```
class Controller {
    var myArray: [AnyObject] 

    init(bool: Bool) {
        if bool == true {
            myArray = [10, 11, 12]
        } else {
            myArray = ["Yo", "Ya", "Yi"]
        }
    }
}
```

The problem that I have with this code is that myArray is still (of course) of type [AnyObject] after my class initialization. Thus, every time I need to get an object out of myArray, I have to cast its type (Int or String) just like this:

```
let controller = Controller(bool: false)
let str = controller.array[0] as String
```

I want to be able to write `let str = controller.array[0] //str: String` without having to cast the real type of the objects inside myArray. Is there a way to do so? Do I have to use lazy init, struct, generic types?

Here is a attempt in pseudo code:

```
class Controller {
    var myArray: Array<T> //Error: use of undeclared type 'T'

    init(bool: Bool) {
        if bool == true {
            myArray = [10, 11, 12] as [Int] //myArray: Array<Int>
        } else {
            myArray = ["Yo", "Ya", "Yi"] as [String] //myArray: Array<String>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does your array need to contain variant types at run time? Is this something you could design around? It seems very confusing, I would be thrown by this if I were to jump into the code base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as Oscar and Elijah pointed out (up votes to them), I am just trying to be a little more verbose here. You need to declare the generic, `T`,  when you define the class.

This would mean you need to define what that generic's type is at initialization of the class.

```
class Foo<T> {
    var items = [T]()
}

let stringFoo = Foo<String>()

stringFoo.items.append("bar")
stringFoo.items[0] = "barbar"

stringFoo.items                 // ["barbar"]



let intFoo = Foo<Int>()

intFoo.items.append(1)
intFoo.items[0] = 11

intFoo.items                    // [11]
```

So in your case, rather than passing a `Bool` for the `init` method, just define the generic's type at initialization instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Controller<T> //You missed that T, right?
{ 
    var myArray: Array<T>
    /* initialization stuff */
}

var c = Controller<String>()
c.myArray[0] = "Hey!"
let str = c.myArray[0] //String, eventually!
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Controller<T> {
    var array: Array<T> = []

    ...
}
```

Comment: You can't add a little dialog to this?